# How to display image on SQL Server Reporting Service?

Tags: reporting-services

I want to display an image that already saved in my database to the report.

But I found that the image is not display, somehow maybe something not right with my data of image, therefore here is how the image/file is saved in database

```
<file><name>back ic 2.png</name><content>iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAfQAAAFDCAYAAADMGfxHAAAACXBIWXMAAA7EAAAOxAGVKw4bAAAgAElEQVR4nOS9WZMjSZLn91M1c3dERB5VfWzPksuVpcgK
```

and so on.. (this data is not complete due to limitation of characters)

After research, I found that to display image on SSRS, the data is varbinary. Should I convert to varbinary? if yes, how to do that?

Please help. Thank You.

Comment: Hi Liana. I'm not sure, but the format seems encoded somehow and not the raw binary format. I'd look at what formats are expected/supported in reporting services and see how you can either convert to those formats, or save the images directly in that format instead (this would probably involve storing the image in a varbinary column).

Comment: Typically you would store the image in a varbinary field in SQL Server. SSRS would use this column as the image source. I'm not sure what format your image is currently stored but if you can access the `content` as a field then try `=System.Convert.ToBase64String(Fields!MyImageField.Value)`